# asp.net open new tab and postback event

Tags: asp.net

My asp.net hat is a bit dusty, so hopefully this will be a simple question. 
C# asp.net 4.5

I need a control on my form that will:

- open a page in a new tab (not window because its not showing up on mobile browsers)
- do a postback to a server-side method. I need the server-side callback because I have to modify some databound data.

I can't seem to get both conditions at the same time.

If I use an **asp:Button**, I can get the server-side event, but can't get the new page to open in a tab, rather than a window.

If I use an **asp:HyperLink**, it will open in a new tab, but I can't get a server-side event.

If I use an **asp:LinkButton**, it will open in the current tab. If I set the target="_blank", then I get an error "*'webform_postbackoptions' is undefined*"

**Questions:**

1. Is there a control available that will do both situations correctly?
2. If not, for controls with no URL, what code can I use from the server-side to open a new Tab rather than a Window? (I know its usually up to the browser to decide what to open, but somehow the hyperlink control opens properly, so there must be a way!)
3. OR for controls with no OnClick events, how can I call my server-side function? (from javascript in a client-side event maybe?)

note, any solution that changes the form's target to "_Blank" ruins the functionality of the rest of the page.

Code:

```
protected void btn_Docsign_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Do stuff here         

    //open window - this always opens a window, not a tab
    Page page = (Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler;
    String DocusignLink = "myurl.com"
    if (page != null)
    {
        string script = String.Format(@"window.open(""{0}"", ""{1}"", ""{2}"");", DocusignLink, "_Blank", "toolbar=1,menubar=1,resizable=1,scrollbars=1,top=0,left=0");
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(page, typeof(Page), "Redirect", script, true);
    }

    //Response.Redirect(DocusignLink); //opens in current tab
}
```

Comment: Did you try using ajax to trigger the event, then open a new tab after the call is completed?

Comment: I don't know anything about ajax, can you give me a code sample to try?